# How can I speed up the evaluation of my equations?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, parallelization

Calculation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors in dependence of the parameters

```
ESysNO[NB02_?NumericQ, NB04_?NumericQ, NB06_?NumericQ, NB34_?NumericQ,
NB36_?NumericQ, NB66_?NumericQ, NBz_?NumericQ, NµB_?NumericQ] := Chop[CFEigensystem[N[Apply[HZCF, Thread[{B02, B04, B06, B34, B36, B66, Bz, µB} = {NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NµB}]]], 16]];

EMatNO[NB02_?NumericQ, NB04_?NumericQ, NB06_?NumericQ, NB34_?NumericQ, NB36_?NumericQ, NB66_?NumericQ, NBz_?NumericQ,NµB_?NumericQ] := ESysNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NµB][[1]];

VecMatNO[NB02_?NumericQ, NB04_?NumericQ, NB06_?NumericQ, NB34_?NumericQ, NB36_?NumericQ, NB66_?NumericQ, NBz_?NumericQ, NµB_?NumericQ] := ESysNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NµB][[2]];
```

Calculation of the spectral weights

```
SpecWtLJJm1[Skk_, NB02_, NB04_, NB06_, NB34_, NB36_, NB66_, NBz_] := Sum[VecMatNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, 5.788381806638/10^5][[Skk,kk]]^2*TLJJm1[[kk]], {kk, 1, Length[funlist]}]; 
AbsoluteTiming[SpecWtLJJm1[1, -10, -10, -0.5, -6, 0.4, -1.7, 13]]
{0.0224183, 0.0753555}

SpecWtRJJm1[Skk_, NB02_, NB04_, NB06_, NB34_, NB36_, NB66_, NBz_] := Sum[VecMatNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, 5.788381806638/10^5][[Skk,kk]]^2*TRJJm1[[kk]], {kk, 1, Length[funlist]}]; 
AbsoluteTiming[SpecWtRJJm1[1, -10, -10, -0.5, -6, 0.4, -1.7, 13]]
{0.0226654, 209.262}
```

Calculation of the partition function

```
PartFun[NB02_, NB04_, NB06_, NB34_, NB36_, NB66_, NBz_, NT_] := Sum[E^(-(EMatNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, 5.788381806638/10^5][[Skk]]/(kB*NT))), {Skk, 1, Length[funlist]}]; 
AbsoluteTiming[PartFun[-10, -10, -0.5, -6, 0.4, -1.7, 13, 20.8]]
{0.0210252, 4.32403*10^6}
```

Calculation of the spectral modulation

```
SpecModLJJm1[NB02_, NB04_, NB06_, NB34_, NB36_, NB66_, NBz_, NT_] := Sum[SpecWtLJJm1[Skk, NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz]/E^(EMatNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, 5.788381806638/10^5][[Skk]]/(kB*NT)), {Skk, 1, Length[funlist]}]/PartFun[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NT]; 
AbsoluteTiming[SpecModLJJm1[-10, -10, -0.5, -6, 0.4, -1.7, 13, 20.8]]
{0.363163, 0.189235}

SpecModRJJm1[NB02_, NB04_, NB06_, NB34_, NB36_, NB66_, NBz_, NT_] := Sum[SpecWtRJJm1[Skk, NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz]/E^(EMatNO[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, 5.788381806638/10^5][[Skk]]/(kB*NT)), {Skk, 1, Length[funlist]}]/PartFun[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NT];
AbsoluteTiming[SpecModRJJm1[-10, -10, -0.5, -6, 0.4, -1.7, 13, 20.8]] 
{0.37417, 209.145}
```

Calculation of the whole intensity

```
SpecModXMCAJJm1[NB02_, NB04_, NB06_, NB34_, NB36_, NB66_, NBz_, NT_] :=(SpecModRJJm1[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NT] - SpecModLJJm1[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NT])/(SpecModRJJm1[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NT] + SpecModLJJm1[NB02, NB04, NB06, NB34, NB36, NB66, NBz, NT]);
AbsoluteTiming[SpecModXMCAJJm1[-10, -10, -0.5, -6, 0.4, -1.7, 13, 20.8]]
{1.47653, 0.998192}
```

As you see the evaluation time of the equations increases dramatically starting from the spectral weights over the partition function and resulting in 1.47sec for the evaluation of one single datapoint of the whole intensity. 
How can I optimize my code to get the max evaluation speed out of this?
I want to plot 1000 datapoints and do a fit by varying the parameters. For this reason I need a very fast code.

Comment: in short my equations calculate sums over sums of eigenvectors and eingenvalues

Comment: It looks like you are using Sum where fast numerical functions like Total and Dot may be more appropriate. It's hard to tell, because the code is incomplete.